# Optimizing massive inserts into unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, bcp

Are there any (documented or known undocumented) limits on maximum supported frequency of inserts (simple and BCP) into table; and on maximum parallel high frequency inserts into independent tables?

We have 4 tables (A, B, C, D) that resides in a same DB (sql server 2012, ultimate) and they have their own filegroup - One filegroup for those large tables another for other data - both currently on the same SSD disk. Recovery Mode is simple and log file is on separate SSD disk.
A, B, C, D are indexed chronologically (each has one single clustered index with chronological order) and inserts happens chronologically. No reads from the tables. Inserts are performed by executing insert SP for each new records. We insert up to dozens of records per sec to each of those tables.
Everything works just fine (near 0% CPU on sql server, near 0% disk time for datafile and logfile disks on sql server) until crossing some threshold of frequency of inserts (I don't have exact number, but ~ 100 inserts per sec) I/O (writes and reads) for datafile disk is at 100% and DB is unusable, and (almost) all attempts for insertion timeouts. After stopping our service, DB is quickly to normal, but after restarting and getting to similar threashold of writes situation repeats. There are no signs of this situation approaching - DB is either perfectly quick, or unusable

**What didn't work:**

- creating A, B, C, D from scratch (so that they are empty) - even with
  few thousands of records inside them, situation repeated.
- creating A, B, C, D from scratch as heaps (without any indexes)

**What we are going to do:**

- insert those data through BCP; however there are 5 other tables that
  will need to use this approach also - they will eventually have also
  high frequency of inserts but need to offer data at max 1 second old.

**Actual questions:**

- Can we see clogging with the BCP also?
- Should we somehow limit maximum parallel running BCPs into
  independent tables? (each table will have just single BCP thread, but
  there will be ~9 tables, of which bigger half can have minutes
  delayed data, and few tables need to have around 1 second old data)

Comment: Are your inserts to each table happening concurrently? It sounds like a lock escalation issue (but can't be if a single thread processes all the inserts serially on one table). I'm also slightly wondering if your row sizes are sane, as for your average table (no blobs or huge strings) even row-by-row should manage at least a few thousand inserts per second, and BCP, say, 50k per second. If you're using ADO.NET, have a look at SqlBulkCopy (you don't need to run the command-line utility).

Comment: @TheDag Yes - currently all inserts are concurrent - so we insert to single table from several threads. However ActivityMonitor wasn't showing any deadlocks (and no transaction ends as deadlock victim - everything just times out). Rows should be max around 1KB each (there are few numeric values and 2-3 small varchar values and one varchar(1024))
Yes - I'm planning to use exactly SqlBulkCopy class (and make sure that each table is accessed from single thread). However still worried if the issue can reoccur with the new design.

Comment: What wait types do you get when it all gets "clogged"?

Comment: @MartinSmith Majority of inserts are blocked by one insert in progress (from sp_who2) - even inserts into A are sometimes blocked by inserts to B, despite they do not reference each other (or do not have trigger updating same table); only common thing is few FKs to some 'enum tables'. It's a good point to find out actual wait type of inserts on top of waiting chain (those not blocked) - will try to find out those (once I'll have repro in isolated test environment). Thanks!

Comment: It seems there is something terribly wrong with the method of inserting. I have a much less impressive setup for datawarehousing purposes and my inserts (bulk insert, 1 thread per table) easily do 5k to 10k per second per table, up to 3 tables at the same time. Can you share some more data on what exactly you are doing? What program/procedure/commands are you using to insert the data, any exotic db configs, etc.

Comment: yeah, sounds like some serious contention somewhere.  Make sure to share all your indices as well as the FK constraints.

Comment: And the fragmentation...   if the indexes are in poor repair, you can get clobbered by escalation, as already mentioned... it is not a deadlock, just awful throttling as the engine can't "batch" anything

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry, I forgot this. I said "lock", not "deadlock". SQL server may choose to escalate a lock, deciding that it takes more resources to manage row-level locks "than it's worth". Unfortunately, although a page lock level supposedly exists, AFAIK MSSQL will, if it decides to escalate, always go directly to the table level. This won't cause a deadlock, but it will cause all but the transaction holding the table lock to wait (and eventually time out if the client uses a command timeout). Apart from using BCP (or SqlBulkCopy if you're on ADO.NET), minimizing row size will help.

Answer (score 0):

Several things come to mind:

1. What is the Recovery mode (can you set it to simple)?
2. Do you have a lot of indexes on the tables that may need to be currently updated (try dropping until the import completes, then add)
3. Do you ahve FKs that have to be referenced, but have no indexing.  It could be read contention
4. Have you determinred reads/writes to the disk?  That may clue you in a bit.
5. Is there long running transactions?

The answers to some of that may clue you in a bit as to what hte actual challenges are in your system.